# "First year birthday" or "first birthday"

Tags: meaning

What should I say to refer to the baby's first year birthday? The baby turns one year old on that day. Is it correct to say *first birthday party* or should I say *first year birthday party*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily one would call a party for a first birthday a “first birthday party”, or might write “first-birthday party” if concerned about ambiguity.  Phrase “first year birthday party” would not be used.  Phrase “first-year birthday party” *could* be used, and avoids the slight ambiguity mentioned before.  (A 3-year-old baby having his or her first party for a birthday *could* be said to be at a “first birthday party”.  While few people would use the phrase that way, some people might write “first birthday-party” to intend such meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

Only after completion of a year are all parties (birth, marriage, etc.) celebrated. That ensures that you have completed that number of years and never take the running number of the year into account.

Comment: The question isn't about counting the year(s).